# Where can I find the pMON7124 plasmid sequence?

Tags: sequence-analysis, plasmids

I need the map of the pMON7124 plasmid. As this is not easy to find, I welcome any hints.

Comment: perhaps contact these people (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC237841/pdf/jvirol00029-0122.pdf) as these seems to be one of the original papers working with the plasmid.

Comment: Addgene is a good site to find plasmids

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that no good map of this plasmid is around. Life technology uses it in some of its bacterial strains, the quote:

> E. coli also contain the helper plasmid, pMON7124 (13.2 kb), which
>   encodes the transposase and confers resistance to tetracycline. The
>   helper plasmid provides the Tn7 transposition function in trans.

They link to the original publication, but the image quality in there is pretty bad:

[image]

They give some information in the text, so I would recommend reading the paper (if you have no access, let me know, I can help here):

- [A broad-host-range shuttle system for gene insertion into the
  chromosomes of gram-negative bacteria.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2850977)

If this is not enough, you could still try to get a better version from the author Gerard F. Berry (you can find his Monsanto email adress by googling for it).